# Java wierd error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at app.trackint.getmean(trackint.java:79)

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Hi all  im trying to make a class that takes an array as a parameter and returns the min , max , mean and most frequent element in that array. However when make making an instance of the class im getting  a wierd error saying   `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException    at app.trackint.getmean(trackint.java:79)`  Can someone please help me ? Thanks for the help everyone !!! 
  Thanks for the help everyone !!!

```
/**
 *
 * @author User
 */


import java.util.Arrays;
public class trackint{


     private int[] array;

    public trackint(int[] a){


 a = new int[2];



    }

    public void getmax(int[] array){

      // Initialize maximum element 
         int max = array[0];

         for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
             if (array[i] > max) {
                 max = array[i]; 
             }
         System.out.println(max); 
     } 



    }


   public void getmin(int min){

        min = array[0];

         for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
             if (array[i] < min) {
                 min = array[i]; 
             }
    System.out.println(min); 
     } 



    }

       public void getmax(int max){

      // Initialize maximum element 
        max = array[0];

         for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
             if (array[i] > max) {
                 max = array[i]; 
             }
      System.out.println(max); 
     } 
       }

        public void getmean(){

      // Initialize maximum element 

        float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
   System.out.println( sum / array.length);
     } 





       public void mostFrequent(int n, int[] array) {



        // find the max frequency using linear 
        // traversal 
        int max_count = 1, res = array[0]; 
        int curr_count = 1; 

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
        { 
            if (array[i] == array[i - 1]) 
                curr_count++; 
            else 
            { 
                if (curr_count > max_count) 
                { 
                    max_count = curr_count; 
                    res = array[i - 1]; 
                } 
                curr_count = 1; 
            } 
        } 

        // If last element is most frequent 
        if (curr_count > max_count) 
        { 
            max_count = curr_count; 
            res = array[n - 1]; 
        } 

       System.out.println( res); 

     } 


     public static void main(String []args){

        int[] array =  {1,2,3,4,5};
        trackint a  = new trackint(array);
        a.getmean();

     }
}
```

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Class namens should Start with uppercase character. Use camel case in method namens

Comment: 1) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556) 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 4) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. ..

Comment: .. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your constructor,

Your constructor does not correctly initializes the instance variable int[] array due to which it remains null and throws NullPointerException at this code array.length,

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // here array is null so throws NPException
```

You need to make your constructor like this,

```
public trackint(int[] a) {
    array = a;
}
```

instead of,

```
public trackint(int[] a) {    
        a = new int[2];    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public trackint(int[] a){
    a = new int[2];
}
```

This is reassigning the `a` local variable. Instead you should do this

```
public trackint(int[] a){
    array = a;
}
```

which will set `array` to the value of `a`.

I haven't tested this though. So, please comment below if you face any problem with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize `array`:

```
public trackint(int[] a){
    array = a;
}
```

or

```
public trackint(int[] a) {
    array = new int[a.length];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, array, 0, a.length);
}
```

or just pass your array to the getmean function.